# iReport statement in field expression

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports, ireport

There is a call of method with 3 parameters in table field of Ireport. In some cases two arguments of this method can be null.But then throws an exception:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
  No signature of method: static su.petrosoft.api.convertregofdesicion.DesicionConv.convDesicion()
  is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, null, null),
Possible solutions: convDesicion(java.lang.String, java.lang.Float)
```

Why this exception throws and what to do in this case?

Comment: Are you sure there's a static 3 parameter function; `DesicionConv.convDesicion`?  Groovy is saying there's only a 2 parameter static function which takes a String and a Float...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Groovy says that method with 2 parameters just a possible solution.

Comment: Can you post the code to prove this?  If there were a `static` method with 3 params, groovy would show it as a potential solution...  Sure it's `static` in the `DesicionConv` class?

Comment: You are right, the method was not static. Thanks for help!

Comment: can you please post your solution as answer or delete your question? This will remove this question form the list of unanswered ones...

Answer (score 0):

As commmented by user1301035 the **method was not `static`**